# How are Yakshinis of very beautiful bodies while Yakshasa are dwarfish?

Tags: creation

How are Yakshinis of very beautiful bodies while Yakshasa are dwarfish?

Yakshasa sometimes are depicted as formidable warriors. Are the formidable warriors' bodies of the Yakshasa their true bodies?